# Don't remove the record from Apache Solr

Tags: nodes, search

I have a custom module, which delete the records in DB based on Cron using node_delete_multiple.

For search reason, I don't want to remove the record from Apache Solr when node_delete_multiple function triggers.

We could exclude certain individual nodes using hook_apachesolr_exclude being Index. Am looking to exclude nodes not to remove from index, apachesolr_don't_delete_node_from_index().

Comment: I imagine you have good reasons for your decisions. However my recent experience with Views and search api solr is that if solr returns results to Views that aren't in your local database you will get error 500.

Comment: What I am thinking is to create a new tables to store the data from `search_dataset` and `search_index` tables as they are constantly being updated by `search_reindex` api. You may need to implement `hook_update_index()` or similar `hook` to tweak the query to use the custom tables you created. That way you can avoid the removal of deleted nodes. Check also `hook_search_reset()`.